# OpenIddict Custom provider

Tags: c#, openiddict

I am playing around with the new providers in OpenIddict (from here https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/694), and I am attempting to create my own version for an SSO that is not currently supported.

I understand that the files for the current providers are generated using source generators, however, I have attempted to created my own Builder/Configuration/Options.  I can get the functionality to redirect me to the SSO and then return me back, where I can then get an access token.  However, when the client attempts to perform the step:

*The event OpenIddict.Client.OpenIddictClientEvents+ValidateTokenContext was marked as rejected by OpenIddict.Client.OpenIddictClientHandlers+Protection+ValidateIdentityModelToken.*

I am constantly receiving the following signature error that I cannot figure out exactly why:

*Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.*

My assumption is that once the Access Token has been retrieved the Client is trying to verify the signature.  As part of my custom Configuration I am specifying the *JwksUri* which I hoped would allow the Client to automatically get the signature.  I also tried setting the *JsonWebKeySet* with the signature but this still failed.

Am I missing something with exactly what security key is being used to attempt to verify the signature?

For reference, my custom Configuration is as follows:

```
public sealed partial class CustomOpenIddictClientWebIntegrationConfiguration
{
    public sealed class MyAccount : IConfigureOptions<OpenIddictClientOptions>,
                                              IPostConfigureOptions<CustomOpenIddictClientWebIntegrationOptions.MyAccount>
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

        public MyAccount(IServiceProvider provider)
            => _provider = provider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));

        public void PostConfigure(string? name, CustomOpenIddictClientWebIntegrationOptions.MyAccount options)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.ClientId))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"clientId not provided for {CustomProviders.MyAccount}");
            }
        }

        public void Configure(OpenIddictClientOptions options)
        {
            // Resolve the provider options from the service provider and create a registration based on the specified settings.
            CustomOpenIddictClientWebIntegrationOptions.MyAccount settings = _provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<CustomOpenIddictClientWebIntegrationOptions.MyAccount>>().CurrentValue;

            string environmentUrl = "REDACTED";

            OpenIddictClientRegistration registration = new OpenIddictClientRegistration
            {
                ProviderName = CustomProviders.MyAccount,
                ProviderOptions = settings,
                Issuer = new Uri(environmentUrl, UriKind.Absolute),
                ClientId = settings.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = settings.ClientSecret,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = settings.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = settings.RedirectUri,
                Configuration = _DetermineConfig(environmentUrl)
            };

            registration.Scopes.UnionWith(settings.Scopes);

            options.Registrations.Add(registration);
        }

        private OpenIddictConfiguration _DetermineConfig(string environmentUrl)
        {
            OpenIddictConfiguration config = new OpenIddictConfiguration
            {
                Issuer = new Uri(environmentUrl, UriKind.Absolute),
                AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri($"{environmentUrl}authorize", UriKind.Absolute),
                TokenEndpoint = new Uri($"{environmentUrl}token", UriKind.Absolute),
                UserinfoEndpoint = new Uri($"{environmentUrl}userinfo", UriKind.Absolute),
                EndSessionEndpoint = new Uri($"{environmentUrl}logout", UriKind.Absolute),
                DeviceAuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri($"{environmentUrl}devicecode", UriKind.Absolute),
                JwksUri = new Uri($"{environmentUrl}jwk", UriKind.Absolute),
                CodeChallengeMethodsSupported = { "plain", "S256" },
                GrantTypesSupported = { "authorization_code", "implicit", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", "client_credentials", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant_type:redelegate", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code", "refresh_token" },
                ResponseModesSupported = { "query" },
                ResponseTypesSupported = { "code", "token" },
                ScopesSupported = { "openid", "profile", "ucrn", "contactmobile", "contactlandline", "offline_access", "nec", "chi", "preferredname" },
                DeviceAuthorizationEndpointAuthMethodsSupported = { "client_secret_post" },
                TokenEndpointAuthMethodsSupported = { "client_secret_post" },
            };
            
            return config;
        }
    }
}
```

My Program.cs for the Client setup looks like:

```
.AddClient(options =>
            {
                options
                    .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();

                // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
                if (certificates is null)
                {
                    options.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey();
                    options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    options.AddEncryptionCertificate(certificates.EncryptionCertificate);
                    options.AddSigningCertificate(certificates.SigningCertificate);
                }

                options.UseAspNetCore()
                    .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                    .EnableRedirectionEndpointPassthrough();
                
                options
                    .UseWebProviders()
                    .UseMyAccount(options =>
                    {
                        options
                            .SetClientId("REDACTED")
                            .SetClientSecret("REDACTED")
                            .SetRedirectUri("callback/login/myaccount")
                            .AddScopes("profile");

                        options.UseTestEnvironment();
                    });
            })
```

Any help would be appreciated.